# Canvas empty in Cypress screenshots

Tags: html5-canvas, cypress

I would like to use Cypress to test a web page that lets users draw on the HTML canvas.

My test involves a sequence of clicks on the canvas followed by `cy.screenshot` (To be precise, four clicks, each one followed by a call to `screenshot` so that I should be able to look through the screenshots and see the image develop click by click.)

When I watch the tests run in interactive mode, I see objects appear on the canvas as expected.  However, after the tests complete, when I examine the screenshot files, the canvas is blank.  The rest of the page appears as expected.

The tests run as expected from the command line using `cypress run` -- I can see the objects on the canvas as expected.

I am running Cypress 3.2.0 on MacOS 10.14.4.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you running your tests in Chrome/Electron? Does running your test in the other browser allow the screenshot to be captured? There's no open issues regarding `<canvas>` support from what I can see, but you may have highlighted an issue here

Comment: I launch cypress from the command line using `cypress open`.  Then click on the spec file to run the tests.  The test run inside a private window opened by cypress.

Comment: In the top-right corner of the Cypress application, there is a drop down menu where you can swap browsers. Check it please and let me know if you're running in Chrome or Electron, and if swapping the browser makes any difference.

Comment: Picture of the switcher: https://i.imgur.com/gbt2Sr2.png

Comment: How strange: Just now, I ran using Chrome 73, then Electron 59.  When I click on the name of the spec file, it takes almost 90 seconds for the browser window to launch and open.  But, once it opened, the tests mostly ran as expected: I can watch the canvas get drawn on as the tests run, and  the screenshot files contained the expected images; but, the "-SCREENSHOT" steps in the test runner contain a blank canvas.  (The last part isn't an issue for me; I just thought you might find the information helpful.)

Comment: I'm having this issue too. Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn’t.